Metabase displays DateTime in strange ways for years far ago
We got a question when looking at a production Metabase v0.32, located in MST (Mountain Standard Time) with PostgreSQL v10 as its application database, and the data sources include MariaDB and SQL Server.
For a DateTime value of early years, e.g., 1900-01-01, we intuitively expect to see a display like 1900-01-01T00:00:00.000 meaning the timestamp at the beginning of the day. However, we get 1900-01-01T00:00:00.000-07:33:52, especially the Timezone indicator, -07:33:52 looks strange.
We discovered more issues by testing more to even earlier years, e.g., 1899-12-31, and the strange display came in different ways, like 1899-12-30T23:26:08.000-07:33:52. So, the time of the day, T23:26:08, also looked strange.
For both MariaDB and SQL Server data sources, we observed the same strange system behavior. So, we wonder why.
We are new to this area, so we highly appreciate any hints and suggestions. And, please let us know if we need more information.
Screenshot:
Please see the following screenshot of our testing on MariaDB data source, and SQL Server data source has the same behavior. And please let us know if you need more details.

Many thanks again for your patience and help.

Have you implemented the recommendations from this page: https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/configuring-metabase/timezones
